# Use client id, affinity id and customer id without using GTM

Tags: google-analytics-4

On a website, the client ID, affinity ID, and customer ID are being displayed in the pageviews under of GA4  when a user logs in, but without using Google Tag Manager. I want to know how it can be possible?

NOTE: I'm watching this event by omnibug extension.

I had tried many times to check code in gtm account but actually there are no found any tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely done directly through gtag.js: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/configure

Other TMSes can send GA events easily while coexisting with GTM.

And, of course, you can send any payload to any endpoint with pure JS.